# Undefined javascript with richfaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces

wonder if you can help me.  For some reason, I am getting javascript errors for my richface components, and this has seemed to have happened without any changes to the code that was working correctly just a few days ago.

Anyway, as an example I am using a rich:componentControl as follows:

```
<a4j:commandButton onclick="#{rich:component('headerpopup')}.show()" id="addheader"  styleClass="saveState" value="Add Column Header">

    <rich:componentControl for="headerpopup" attachTo="addheader" operation="show" event="onclick"/>

</a4j:commandButton>
```

And the javascript error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined
```

I'm suspecting I am missing a javascript file that Richfaces should be providing, is this correct?

I'm using Richfaces 3.3.1 on Jboss 5.1.0 and Seam 2.2.2.

Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops....

It was a schoolboy error:

I had removed the jQuery noConflict line, not knowing what it was...

```
<script>var $e = esiQuery.noConflict();</script>
```